# Permissions across various devices

Tags: server, permissions, samba, transmission, groups

Not sure how to set permissions up across 3 different uses of 1 server.

I'm using samba, Transmission and plex.

Currently I use `/samba/data/media` as my data folder this folder is set with `force user = root` because it's at home, so only accessible by me. 
I have also added `users = @smbgrp` to the **/etc/samba/smb.conf** file

Plex is pointed at this media folder to find media files. Plex has also been added to the group **smbgrp**

Transmission is pointed at `/home/completed-downloads/` and I rsync all new downloads to the /samba/data/media.

I'd like to setup so I can put all completed files in `/**samba/data**/completed-downloads/` but my issue is that downloads are owned by user **debian-transmission** while the /samba/data/ directory is owned by **root** because of `force user = root`.

What would you recommend as the best way of structuring usernames and group permissions? 
so I don't have to manually set permission for new media files each time. I know I can use **--chmod=** during rsync, but I feel like there should be a better way and thought I might learn something in the process.

Options:?

1) Should I create and `force user = sambauser` and then add `plex, debian-transmission, sambauser` to each other's groups?

2) Should change the username used by each application when I install it, so all files have a common username

3) Is there a way to set the user **datauser** primary group as **smbgrp**, instead a group of it's own name?

Any other suggestions I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From research, there are many possible answers to this question, but the one I decided up on was the following.

1) Change permissions to 2770 `chmod -R 2770 /directory/` and change group owner to data, so my persmissions would read `drwxrws---`.

This results in any new folders created by any user to take on the group of it's parent directory.

2) I added all the users to my common data group which is `smbgrp` with.
'usermod -aG smbgrp plex'
'usermod -aG smbgrp debian-transmission'
etc

Hope this helps someone - Do correct me if I'm wrong.